# javascript - recursive setTimeout results in inconsistent behaviour

Tags: javascript

I have a `setTimeout` being called in a recursive function:

```
var recursiveTimer = function(duration, data) {
    anotherFunction(data);

    setTimeout(function() {
        // Do stuff with data
        data = {};

        recursiveTimer(duration, data);
    }, duration);
};
```

Problem here is that my `anotherFunction` is not always called. I experience that it is being called every other time the `recursiveTimer` runs.

How can that be?

**EDIT**:

What my `anotherFunction()` really does, is that it animates a dom element with jQuery. Like this:

```
$('#slider .slider-loader').find('.bg').css('width', "0%");

currentLoader.find('.bg').animate({
    width: "100%"
}, 3000);
```

The first line is where the problem is. It is not being fired *every* time, only every *other* time.

Comment: Works for me. I replaced `anotherFunction` with `alert`, and called `recursiveTimer(5000, "foo");`, and I got an alert every 5 seconds.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/svgm9/

Comment: I have updated my answer with some more details.

Comment: Probably the `.bg` is still animated at the time you enter `anotherFunction` try to clear its animation queue before you call `.css`

Comment: Maybe every *other* time is after the animation finished?

Comment: What duration are you setting when you call recursiveTimer?

Comment: Aha. So I can't apply CSS to a dom element which is (maybe) yet animating? @Barmar - it's the same as the animation, 3000ms.

Comment: @KristianB jquery stores the initial values of the properties that are animated and uses them until the animation is finished. So setting a css property that is currently animated has no effect.

Comment: @t.niese - amazing that so little modification helps! Create an answer and you will get credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based one your comment and the edit your problem is a that the `.bg` is still animated what you observe the wrong behavior.

JQuery stores the initial values of the properties that are animated and uses them until the animation is finished. So setting a css property that is currently animated has no effect.

To avoid this problem you have to stop the animation of the element before you change set the css property:

```
$('#slider .slider-loader').find('.bg').stop(true).css('width', "0%");
```

There are two methodes that can be use to clear the queue [jQuery.clearQueue](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) and [jQuery.stop](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

A note to animation times and timeout duration.
If you set a animation to a duration of `3000ms` the animation also could last `3010ms` (or even longer), same is for the `setTimeout` so you never should count on its accuracy.

Comment: +1 for explanation, but it would be better to wait for the animation instead of canceling it

Comment: Thanks! I don't think my code counts on the accuracy of `setTimeout` and/or animations. The animation is only started when the callback of `setTimeout` is triggered. I experience very consistent behaviour now, which is great!

Comment: @KristianB well you use setTimeout and animation duration in combination which could lead into a _racing condition_ if setTimeout or animation is finished early, that's what i tried to explain.

Comment: @Bergi Depends on the point of view, i would not make my code logic depending on a (_probably_) indication animation. Anyway a **+1** for the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

> The timeout is the same as the animation

You should not do that. Instead, use the `complete` callback parameter of the [`animate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
var bg = $('#slider .slider-loader').find('.bg');
var recursiveTimer = function(duration, data) {
    bg.animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 3000, function() {
        // Do stuff with data
        data = {};
        bg.css('width', "0%");
        recursiveTimer(duration, data);
    });
};
```